# Signal plotting on a paper

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, time-domain

[image]I needed help in plotting this in a paper, I have 2 signals:

x(t) = 4 Tri ((t + T) / 2T)

x(t) = sin((2 pi t)/ T).rect((t - 3T) / 2T)

I have added my solutions to these signals in the attached image, do they look somewhat correct, I'm just doubtful with the operations I performed !!

Thanks for any kind of infos on this -:)

update 1:
[image]

Comment: start by drawing the two separately on the same graph and updating your question to show your result- this will help highlight where you are stuck. It can help to test your result with a single value for t near where you think there are obvious features in your plot, and plug that in to the formula to compute x(t) and then confirm if that matches your plot.   Even start with drawing x(t)=Tri(t) and then x(t)=Tri((t+T)) and spending time with that to figure it out together with the math as I described - there is no replacement for doing this several times with variations until you get it.

Comment: @DanBoschen I have added my solution, could you please help me out with the validation of these..

Comment: Your part 1 doesn’t look right so I didn’t review part 2. Stick with part 1 first: the $4tri(t/To)$ looks right but nothing else does. Try drawing $tri(t/(2T_o)$ and validate yourself using the method I described. Then scale by 4 and shift by $T_o$.

Comment: The $A tri(t)$ becomes zero when the input $t=-1$ and $t=1$, and $A$ when $t=0$. For what values of $t$ satisfy $(t+T_0)/(2T_0)=-1$ and $(t+T_0)/(2T_0)=1$ and $(t+T_0)/(2T_0)=0$? More generally, how would an input $(t+a)/b$ affect translation and horizontal scaling?

Comment: ok so I have updated based on the comments, following the general definition of a triangular signal. From t = -3T --> -T --> +T the general definition satisfies..

Comment: Your update looks correct. You can apply the same procedure for the second part; find where the peaks/troughs and/or boundaries of the basic function are (e.g., $sin(t)$ and $rect(t)$) and determine how those values of $t$ change. Remember that periodic functions will have multiple solutions such as zeros at $n\pi$ for all integer values of $n$.